# JavaFX - Make an icon button like Photoshop

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to make a photoshop like interface for one of my projects. But I have some issues when I'm trying to put an icon on my button.

Here's my fxml :

```
<GridPane fx:id="grid" style="-fx-border-width: 0 1 0 0; -fx-border-color: black;">
        <padding><Insets top="5"/></padding>
        <Button stylesheets="@buttons-style.css" styleClass="fill-btn"
        onAction="#but"
        prefHeight="30" prefWidth="30"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        GridPane.columnSpan="2">
        <graphic>
            <ImageView fitHeight="10.0" fitWidth="10.0">
                <image>
                    <Image url="https://www.iconexperience.com/_img/o_collection_png/green_dark_grey/512x512/plain/shape_circle.png" />
                </image>
             </ImageView>
        </graphic>
        </Button>
</GridPane>
```

This is my GridPane on the left of my BorderPane which is the root pane of my application. I made a css file to make it easier so here it is :

```
.fill-btn {
-fx-background-color: inherit;
-fx-opacity: inherit;
}
```

I tried a lot of solutions but I can't find a way to make something equivalent to photoshop button design. Someone can help me ?

**Edit**

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTAVa.png)

Here's a screenshot of what I get, the circle on the left is the button I made, it doesn't fill the button correctly. I have a screenshot with the background of the button.

[Button with the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NdQP.png)

so you can see the icon doesn't fill my button.

[Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2xHG.jpg)

This is the the result I would like to have but only for the left part. My project is making a Hackenbush game with the possibility of making his own playground. So I need an editing part on the left like photoshop have.

**Edit 2**

I noticed the both link to 2 others post, but they're not using FXML, and I, I'm using it, so the solution is different and their solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: it would really help to have screenshots of what you want to achieve and what you already did.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev I made it, but like I said I want the exact design of photoshop with icon for button